# Remote Connect to Jboss Application-Server - NamingIOException cause by ClassNotFound

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, ejb-3.0

First of all this is my first question on StackOverflow and I'm an Intern in a Company in Germany, so My English is a little broken and my Knowledge might be limited.

I Try to connectio to a Jboss 6.1.0 eap remotely.
I'm using Eclipse as IDE for the EJB and the EAR but I run the Jboss form cmd

My ejb3 definition look like that:

```
package de.jack;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface TestServiceRemote {
    public void sayRemote();

}

package de.jack;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class TestService
 */
@Stateless
public class TestService implements TestServiceRemote {

    public TestService() {  }

    public void sayRemote() {
        System.out.println("\n\nHello");
    }
}
```

After gernerating the .ear file I deploy them in the JBoss AS and all that works fine
I can view them in the browser under localhost:9990 and check that they are deployed

Now to the Part where I fail - the Client:

```
public static void main(String argv[]){

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jack");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "katze");
        props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        // create a context passing these properties
        InitialContext context;
        Object test = null;
        try {
            context = new InitialContext(props);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            test = 
                 context.lookup("ConnectorBean/TestService!de.jack.TestServiceRemote");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

On Run I get the exception:

```
org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.NamingIOException: Failed to lookup [Root exception is java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.jack.TestServiceRemote]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:49)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:104)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:95)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$1.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:245)
...
```

I not sure what exactly I did wrong
one reason could be that I do not have admin-rights on the maschine or I mixed up the properties on Client side

Sorry for my bad english and I'm very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. modify TestService class

   ```
   @Stateless
   @Remote(TestServiceRemote.class)  
   public class TestService implements TestServiceRemote {

       public TestService() {  }

       public void sayRemote() {
           System.out.println("\n\nHello");
       }
   }
   ```
2. ensure remote client has a reference of TestServiceRemote.class
3. change lookup jndi name

   ```
     // The app name is the application name of the deployed EJBs. This is typically the ear name
   // without the .ear suffix. However, the application name could be overridden in the application.xml of the
   // EJB deployment on the server.
   // Since we haven't deployed the application as a .ear, the app name for us will be an empty string
   final String appName = "";
   // This is the module name of the deployed EJBs on the server. This is typically the jar name of the
   // EJB deployment, without the .jar suffix, but can be overridden via the ejb-jar.xml
   // In this example, we have deployed the EJBs in a jboss-as-ejb-remote-app.jar, so the module name is
   // jboss-as-ejb-remote-app
   final String moduleName = "jboss-as-ejb-remote-app";
   // AS7 allows each deployment to have an (optional) distinct name. We haven't specified a distinct name for
   // our EJB deployment, so this is an empty string
   final String distinctName = "";
   // The EJB name which by default is the simple class name of the bean implementation class
   final String beanName = TestService.class.getSimpleName();
   // the remote view fully qualified class name
   final String viewClassName = TestServiceRemote.class.getName();

   String jndiName= "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName;

   TestServiceRemote service = (TestServiceRemote)context.lookup(jndiName);
   ```

Detail please reffer: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Answer (score 0):

Server log should show correct global JNDI name for the bean. It should be like foo/EJB-NAME/remote. Then you need change it in context.lookup("ConnectorBean/TestService!de.jack.TestServiceRemote").

Please check -
http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/JNDI_Bindings.html